# affine and projective schemes over $\mathbf{F}_1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, field-with-one-element

What should affine and projective schemes over $\mathbf{F}_1$ be?

Comment: Dear OP: Please define $\mathbb{F}_1$, otherwise I feel this question is meaningless.

Comment: There is an overview paper on the arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0069 "Mapping F_1 land". 

Comment: I vote to close. This question is not precise enough and not really specific. And every one can simply type the question into google and will see that a lot of work has been done in the last years on that. You don't need to ask here to find this.

Comment: And of course the paper mentioned by Lars is one of the many points of departure for the literature.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds rather vague, but in any case, you might be interested in the paper "On the notion of geometry over $\mathbb{F}_1$" by Alain Connes and Caterina Consani, available on the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2926) (or on Connes' homepage http://www.alainconnes.org).